# '+' string operator and StringBuilder in BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry, stringbuilder

I have a problem with BlackBerry JDE 6.0 The following code give me the warning (and cause error at runtime)

```
 String s = "hello";
 doSomeStuff(s + "world");
```

The warning:

```
Warning!: Reference to undefined class: java.lang.StringBuilder
```

I don't use any StringBuilder. I have searched and found *The most recent version of RIM API does not contain StringBuilder class*.

Changing JRE version into 1.4 can help, but it gave me a big trouble because I couldn't use generic collection and some new apis in this version.
Another solution is I can use **StringBuffer**, but can't I simply use '+' operator? Why is it hard to try?
**Update**:
I looking for another way to use '+' operator, because my code has used many of them and I don't want to spend many time to replace all of them.

Comment: I'm willing to bet its an issue with the fact that you're concatenating while passing in the value.

Comment: you cannot use `StringBuilder` its not supported in Blackberry you can use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder` ...

Comment: Wow google is fast.  This question is already on the first page for "blackberry jde stringbuilder".

Comment: Please take a look in my updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Java compiler will automatically convert any expression with a series of string concatenations to use a buffer.  Before Java 1.5, there was only one choice - StringBuffer.  However, it suffered from the convention in early Java of synchronizing all public methods.   In Java 1.5 a new buffer class was added - StringBuilder - which is better because it drops synchronization, leaving it up to users of the class to properly synchronize access.  When the Java compiler is targeting Java 1.5 or later, it will use StringBuilder.  For pre-1.5, it will use StringBuffer.

BlackBerry devices use Java-ME, which is based on Java 1.3, so no StringBuilder class is present.  Your problem is that you are writing modern Java-SE code and expecting to deploy it on a Java-ME BlackBerry device.   If you are using Eclipse, change your Java language compliance level to 1.3.  This will make the compiler properly produce StringBuffer references.  It will also make use of generics a syntax error.  This is expected for BlackBerry development - you don't get generics.

Example code:

```
public class test {
    public static String concat(String a, String b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Bytecode result when compiled with `javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 test.java`

```
public static java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_0
   8:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   11:  aload_1
   12:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   15:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   18:  areturn
```

Bytecode result when compiled with `javac -source 1.3 -target 1.3 test.java`

```
public static java.lang.String concat(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuffer
   3:   dup
   4:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer."<init>":()V
   7:   aload_0
   8:   invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
   11:  aload_1
   12:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuffer;
   15:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/StringBuffer.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
   18:  areturn
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it. I'm new to BlackBerry, so I 'm confuse about BB  's inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilders are used implicitly when you append strings with the + operator.  Because Strings are immutable, repeatedly appending is an O(n^2) operation.  The solution is StringBuilders, which have amortized O(n) append time and are implicitly used whenever you use the + operator on a string and something else.  That code is expanding internally to:

```
doSomeStuff(new StringBuilder().append(s).append("world").toString());
```

You should be able to get around this with the following:

```
doSomeStuff(s.append("world"));
```

However, because that falls back onto the problem that StringBuilders are intended to solve, consider falling back upon the StringBuffer implementation that others have suggested.

You could maybe try writing your own StringBuilder class that wrapped StringBuffer.  I think the only methods you would need to expose are a bunch of append(?)s (one for every primitive type, one for String, and one for Object that calls the objects toString and falls back on the String one) and a toString().  I have no idea if that will work or not, it depends on whether or not the code generated by the compiler uses the fully qualified name of StringBuilder or not.  But it might be worth a try.  Aside from that I can't think of any other ways you could make it work, aside from the chance that you can find a switch that turns off generation of code with StringBuilders in it when you use the + operator.

You could try something like:

```
class StringBuilder
{
    StringBuffer buf = null;
    public StringBuilder()
    {
        buf = new StringBuffer();
    }
    public StringBuilder append(StringBuilder other)
    {
        buf.append(other.buf);
        return this;
    }
    public StringBuilder append(String s)
    {
        buf.append(s);
        return this;
    }
    public StringBuilder append(Object o)
    {
        buf.append(o.toString());
        return this;
    }
    public StringBuilder append(int i)
    {
        buf.append(i);
        return this;
    }
    /* SNIP: append() methods for every other primitive type */
    public String toString()
    {
        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

To be honest, I have no idea if that will even work, but its worth a shot.

Comment: You cant use StringBuilder in Blackberry its not supported. So it will never going to be compiled ... Any way and instead of StringBuilder you can replace with StringBuffer ...

Comment: But my code has used many + operator, and I must replace all them with StringBuffer? Is there any way to try it? Please take a look in my updated question

Comment: The compiler inserts the references to StringBuilder in the bytecode, not in the sourcecode.  The bytecode inherently uses fully qualified class names, so this custom class will not work unless you declare it in the java.lang package.  Even if you somehow get that working, you are fundamentally fighting the wrong battle.  The compiler compliance level is clearly wrong for BlackBerry development.

Answer (score 0):

What is the compiler version you're using? 
From what I know , at least from version 1.5, the operator+ is replaced by StringBuilder during compilation, At some scenarios. For example: 
 
When there is a "static" String concatenation like this at code: `String s = "hello" + "world";` 
 
However, when concatenation result cannot be determined at compile time, it will not be able to get translated to StringBuilder. 
Having written all of the above, I do not suggest to rely on compiler optimization techniques and , and would suggest you to use StringBuilder as good practice. 
If you have compilation issues, you should try to explicitly using StringBuffer instead , or further reduce the compiler version 
See also some [optimizations](http://www.precisejava.com/javaperf/j2se/StringAndStringBuffer.htm) advice here.

Comment: Blackberry support java version 1.3 as i know so you dont have StringBuilder class in Blackberry ....

Comment: @zaske: So, we can use '+' operator String in BlackBerry? I wonder why RIM make it difficult to use. Why 're they simple change '+' operator into StringBuffer? Please take a look in my updated question.